# How to ask "open to"?

Tags: translation

E.g. "Is this role open to foreign applicants"?
My thought is "这个职位对外国申请人开放吗" or "这个职位接受外国申请人吗"

Comment: What do you mean by this "role"? A job opening?

Comment: @lilysirius That's right, yeah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one 对……开放 is the way to go.

外国申请人 is understandable but a bit awkward. I would recommend 外籍(foreign national)申请人/者.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for your second sentence, you can just have a slight modification, to make it makes sense: 这个职位接受外国人申请吗？Or you can just say“这个职位接受外国人吗？”. Anyway, I think 99% Chinese are able to understand both of your sentences. Don't be afraid of making mistakes when using Chinese. Be confidence! 加油！

Answer (score 0):

这个职位对外国申请人开放吗? ---> 这个职位对外国**求職人**开放吗?